# How to solve $\int\frac{\ln x}{x^2(\ln (x)-1)^2}dx$ by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{\ln x}{x^2(\ln (x)-1)^2}dx$$

Hello, I haven't be able to solve this integral, I've tried to do $u = \ln (x)-1$ but couldn't make it work, any insight?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$x\ln x-x=u\implies \ln x dx=du\implies\displaystyle \int\frac{du}{u^2}=\dfrac{u^{-1}}{-1}+C=\dfrac{1}{x-x\ln x}+C.$

Comment: I think it should be noted that the motivation of the substitution is because the denominator can be rewritten as $(x(\ln x-1))^2$, and of course the nice fact that $du/dx$ turns out exactly to be the numerator.